# Copy a C# string to an existing pre-allocated `char*`

Tags: c#, string, unsafe

I need to copy a C# string into a `char*`. I have this code, which works, but looks clumsy. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
public unsafe static void GetReply(char* buffer) {
  string reply = "Hello, world"; // or whatever
  // clumsy code:
  var i = buffer;
  foreach (char x in reply.ToCharArray()) {
    *i = x;
    i++;
  }
  *i = '\0';
}
```

Note: `buffer` is guaranteed to point to allocated memory of known length. No problems there.

Comment: Are you sure it's a C# `char` (2 bytes) and not a C/C++ `char` (1 byte)?

Comment: Did you try it with System.Buffer.BlockCopy() ?

Comment: @BenVoigt yep it is - the code I posted works - I just don't like the look of it :P

Comment: @Alaudo that appears to work with `Array`s only, not char pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146626.aspx) which is cleaner and likely also faster than the loop.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach might be:

```
        for(int i = 0 ; i < reply.Length ; i++) {
            buffer[i] = reply[i];
        }
        buffer[reply.Length] =  '\0';
```

You could also use `fixed(char* chars = reply) {...}` and loop over the pointers, but seems overkill.